# How to create 4-up pdfs [without pdfnup, pdfpages]?

Tags: pdf, koma-script, pdfpages

I use a standard KOMA-script class for creating slides [`slides.tex`]. I am wondering if there is a LaTeX package with an option to specify how the output looks like. I would like to create a 4-up .pdf version of `slides.tex` in landscape mode. I know that one could use `pdfpages`, but that would rather require to use a second .tex file containing the pdfpages instructions. I am wondering whether one can omit this additional step and directly tell `slides.tex` that the .pdf should be 4-up and landscape (?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `pgfpages` package (not `pdfpages`) (it's part of TikZ/pgf and documented in section 58 of the TikZ manual) to do this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper, landscape]
\begin{document}
\kant[1-13]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for, many thanks Alan!

Comment: One has to say, though, that it does not preserve hyperlinks (this is also mentioned in the manual). I haven't seen any solution which can provide this (the unix tool `ghostscript` can preserve them for extracting pages, but afaik it can't be used to do 4-ups). Another solution on the unix side (also not preserving hyperlinks but still quite flexible) is to use `pdfjam`:  `pdfjam --fitpaper true --nup 2x2 --delta '1mm 1mm' --scale 0.98 foo.pdf` could be used. The resulting pdf is only slightly larger.